# google nexus 7 development rotation not working

Tags: android, tablet, screen-orientation

I recently started creating a mobile application on the google nexus 7. I have previously tested this application on the kindle fire and both portrait and landscape mode worked on all screens but when I upload the application onto the nexus the application always stays in portrait.

Has anyone run into this or know why the nexus only shows my application in portrait mode?

Comment: I'm new. I don't know what that means.. care to explain?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 is a good overview of answering questions. tldr: You can pick answers to questions you ask here on stackoverflow, giving credit and kudos to the person who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your device rotation lock turned on?  It's in the quick pull down menu.

Comment: by pull down menu he means the one you see by swiping down on the battery/time on the top right...then click "ROTATION LOCKED" and it will set your device to AUTO ROTATE. +1 for asking the question, since some of us find everything on SO faster than any other source.